# how can i keep my motivation high all time?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Can any body help me to know how to keep my motivation on track . sometimes it goes too high and too low. I think Watching videos reading books won't help us , how can  we be good at something do we need love ,motivation and dedication towards the work?. which one of them can make us good at something , Is there any standard answer for this question in philosophy.

Comment: You can also read some biographies of Machiavelli. Florence was his inspiration. Of course he also needed work and money.

Comment: This looks more like a question for https://psychology.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...[passion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-hume-morality/) plays the dominant role in motivating action...

...according to David Hume, as explained in this article published by the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. Cited as a primary source, is *David Hume: A Dissertation on the Passions; The Natural History of Religion*, Tom L. Beauchamp (ed.), Oxford: Clarendon Press, 2007. [Originally published in 1757.]